# ¿Cómo traer valores con JSON en inputs de tipo TIME y DATATIME de HTML?

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax, json

Tengo una consulta, estoy trayendo valores (input) de tipo text, time y datetime, pero resulta que no me muestra los valores de tipo time y datatime... mi index.php es el siguiente

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title></title>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/funciones.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"> 
 </script>

</head>
<body>
 <center>
<br/>
<div id="contenedor">
<br/><br/>
<label>DNI</label>
<input type="text" id="dni">
<br/><br/>
<label>NOMBRE</label>
<input type="text" id="nombre"> 
<br/><br/>
<label>APELLIDO</label>
<input type="time" id="apellido"> 
<br/><br/>
<label>HORA</label>
<input type="time" id="timex"> 
<br/><br/>
<label>FECHA</label>
<input type="datetime" id="fechax"> 
<br/><br/>
<input type="submit" onclick="buscar();" value="buscar">
</div>

<div id="ventana"> 
</div>
</center>

 </body>
</html>
```

Y creo que el problema es acá, en mi funciones.js que llamo los valores de la siguiente manera:

```
function buscar(){

var parametros={"dni": $("#dni").val(),}

$.ajax({

        type: 'post',
        url: 'buscardatos.php',
        data: parametros,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(d){
            $("#nombre").val(d[0]);
            $("#apellido").val(d[1]);
            $("#timex").val(d[2]);
            $("#fechax").val(d[3]);
        }
    });
}
```

Y el buscardatos.php es de la siguiente manera:

```
<?php
 $con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
 mysql_select_db("archivos",$con);

 $dni=$_POST["dni"];
 $rs=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM clie  WHERE dni='$dni'");

 $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($rs);

 $datos_a_enviar = array($row['nombre'], $row['apellido'], $row['tiempo'], $row['fecha']);
  echo json_encode($datos_a_enviar);
 ?>
```

En el momento de llamar en el Ajax creo q es el problema, es por eso que no me devuelve los valores que traigo en time y datetime... ¿cómo se puede llamar?

Comment: Comprueba que realmente al hacer la petición en ajax la consulta te retorna esos campos.

Comment: claro, los valores de nombre y apellido me devuelve normalmente, pero de hoa y fecha no, creo que es por el tipo de input(time y datetime)... es por eso mi pregunta, creo q el cambio es en funciones.js pero nose como seria

Comment: Tenías razón compañero, como no manejaba ese tipo de campos yo los desconocía. Ya actualicé la respuesta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actualicé mi respuesta. Una disculpa. Parece que estás usando una
versión antigua de php. La extensión mysql está obsoleta y ya no es
mantenida desde php 7. Debes usar el conector PDO_MYSQL o MYSQLI
para que tus aplicaciones funcionen de manera "segura" con mysql.

Espero esto te funcione (obviamente deberás hacer unos ajustes):

**SQL:**

```
-- ----------------------------
-- Table structure for usuarios
-- ----------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `usuarios`;
CREATE TABLE `usuarios` (
  `id_usuario` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `nombre_usuario` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `apellido_usuario` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `fecha_usuario` date NOT NULL,
  `tiempo_usuario` time NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_usuario`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

-- ----------------------------
-- Records of usuarios
-- ----------------------------
INSERT INTO `usuarios` VALUES ('1', 'carlos', 'aguado', '2018-09-28', '16:30:43');
```

**PHP:**

```
<?php
//setting header to json
header('Content-Type: application/json');

//database
define('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1');
define('DB_USERNAME', 'root');
define('DB_PASSWORD', '');
define('DB_NAME', 'ajax_example');

$mysqli = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);

//check connection
if(!$mysqli){
    die("Connection failed: " . $mysqli->error);
}

//query to get data from the table
$query = sprintf("SELECT id_usuario, nombre_usuario, apellido_usuario, fecha_usuario, tiempo_usuario FROM usuarios ORDER BY id_usuario");

//execute query
$result = $mysqli->query($query);

//loop through the returned data
$data = array();
foreach ($result as $row) {
    $data = array("id_usuario"=>$row['id_usuario'], "nombre_usuario"=>$row['nombre_usuario'], "apellido_usuario"=>$row['apellido_usuario'], "fecha_usuario"=>$row['fecha_usuario'], "tiempo_usuario"=>$row['tiempo_usuario']);
}

//free memory associated with result
$result->close();

//close connection
$mysqli->close();

//now print the data
print json_encode($data);
```

**HTML+JS:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Ejemplo</title>
        <style type="text/css">


        </style>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery3.min.js"></script>
        <!-- javascript -->
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function buscar(){

                $.ajax({
                    url: "data2.php",
                    method: "GET",
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success: function(data) {
                        console.log(data);
                        alert(data.nombre_usuario);
                        $("#nombre").val(data.nombre_usuario);
                        $("#apellido").val(data.apellido_usuario);
                        $("#timex").val(data.tiempo_usuario);
                        $("#fechax").val(data.fecha_usuario);
                    },
                    error: function(data) {
                        console.log(data);
                    }
                });

            }

        </script>       
    </head>
    <body>

    <form>
        Nombre: <input type="text" id="nombre"><br>
        Apellido: <input type="text" id="apellido"><br>
        Fecha: <input type="date" id="fechax"><br>
        Tiempo: <input type="time" id="timex"><br>     
        <input type="button" onclick="buscar();" value="BUSCAR">
    </form> 

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: si existen bro, has un ejemplo y te salen valores

Comment: hola bro, he puesto codigo y si ejecuta, pero me devuelve el ultimo registro(de acuerdo al order by), y no el que yo estoy solicitando,

Comment: Te comentaba en la respuesta que de hecho debes ajustar la función donde haces la consulta para que te traiga el resultado que buscas.

Comment: claro, veo que llevas los valores detu AJAX de tipo GET, entonces en el PHP trate de llamarlos de la siguiente manera $_GET['nombre_usuario'] para poder introducirlo en la consulta, pero no recibe el valor

Comment: se podria realizar?

Comment: Tal vez si, pero no te compliques la vida. Personalmente siento que es mejor retornar el json de esa manera (aunque al json le puedes agregar más detalles como un código de estado y un mensaje) y ya con jquery tomas ese json y lo manipulas de la forma que más te convenga.